# How does the Ubuntu installer picks UEFI or legacy?

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I have an HP Elitebook 8460p from around 2012 which had Windows 10 on it. The BIOS is set to legacy, since UEFI is offered only for development purposes, with big warnings not to use it otherwise.

When I used a USB drive to "erase the disk and install" Ubuntu 21.10, everything went fine until the reboot, where I got "no operating system found" (error: 3F0). I checked with gparted and the disk was GPT with an UEFI partition.

This is strange, since Windows was likely in Legacy mode, given the BIOS settings, and also when I checked from the Live USB which mode is in use, I got legacy: there was no /sys/firmware/efi device.

I tried a lot of solutions found online, and at the end I was able to install 18.04 on the disk when I created a MBR partition table.

I didn't keep track of all tests I performed, but I am quite sure I also tried to install 21.10 AFTER putting a MBR partition table, so I'm confused.

**So, how does the Ubuntu installer pick UEFI vs legacy when defining the way to install the system?**

I would like to install 22.04 as soon as it is released and I would like to reformat using ZFS, but I need to know that it will work in Legacy mode, or I need to know how to make it work in Legacy mode.

There is another similar question ([How to avoid UEFI? Installation without UEFI? How to have Ubuntu 19, 20, 21, 22 w/o UEFI? Just no more EFI/UEFI problems?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156258/how-to-avoid-uefi-installation-without-uefi-how-to-have-ubuntu-19-20-21-22)) which is however about how to force Legacy. The solution proposed (MinimalCD) is outdated, from what I understand from the Ubuntu Wiki, deleting the EFI partition from the USB stick (I think) didn't work in my case, and also I'm mainly asking about the way Ubuntu picks the mode.

Edit

To be clear: in the BIOS the (U)EFI has never been active, the live media booted in Legacy, and yet the new install didn't start, showing the "no OS found" error. I tried to activate UEFI in the BIOS and the message did not show up anymore (just got a blank screen), leading me to think the install was in UEFI mode (also due to the UEFI partition).

Comment: FYI:  The presence of a EFI partition & GPT doesn't mean the install was in uEFI mode; I did an QA-test install today on a HP box from 2005; 2005 being well before uEFI existed yet EFI partition was created as it is for some installs; but not others - even on this BIOS only box from 2005 that has no capacity to use an ESP (*depends on ISO & installer*). As I understand it the decision of uEFI or BIOS is made by how the *live* media is booted; if using `calamares` installer media that is even presented to you as information prior to approving install.

Comment: *the decision of uEFI or BIOS is made by how the live media is booted* Exactly! If you want to make sure it boots in Legacy better to disable that "experimental" uEFI part altogether. Otherwise, when booting the live/installation media you should see two options.

Comment: Maybe it was not clear: in the BIOS the (U)EFI has never been active, the live media booted in Legacy, and yet the new install didn't start, showing the error. I tried to activate UEFI in the BIOS and the message did not show up anymore, but the actual boot didn't start either (blank screen... HP was right when they said it was experimental).

Comment: See this [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg) for some pictures of booting the Ubuntu USB in Legacy and UEFI modes.

Comment: @user68186 then it looks like I got UEFI boot from the Live USB, but then after boot I couldn't find any trace of EFI system device. It's quite confusing.

Comment: The UEFI/Legacy setting is only for installed systems. Windows requires gpt partitioning for UEFI boot and requires MBR(msdos) partitioning for BIOS boot. The Ubuntu installer normally does not change partitioning from MBR to gpt with UEFI install unless drive is blank or over 2TB. How you boot install media for both Windows & Ubuntu is then how it installs. Depending on tool used to create installer flash drive, it may be BIOS only or UEFI only, but most tools create a flash drive that can boot in either mode, and you have to select UEFI:XXXX where XXX is your flash drive for UEFI boot.